Can I add a GitHub Pages link to an IEEE paper abstract?
Can I add a GitHub Page link to an IEEE paper abstract? The page has videos, photos, abstract, codes links etc. Is there any restriction for that?
Example:

We provide real robot video demonstrations on our project page
xxxx.github.io/paper-title.


Normally, it is not advisable to add any reference in the abstract. You can, however, add it in the paper after abstract.

I don't know if it's allowed, but you should use something that is more permanent than GitHub for scientific publication. For example, you can archive your repository with Zenodo and generate a DOI. If you connect the repository with Zenodo you can archive all different releases as well.
